# Does chisel3's printf generate terminal output when simulating the emitted verilog?

Tags: chisel

I was looking into `Chiffre` as an option for fault injection in my design and noticed some `when` statements with `printf` in them.

```scala
 when (enabled && RegNext(!enabled)) {
    printf(s"""|[info] $name enabled
               |[info]   - seed: 0x%x
               |[info]   - difficulty: 0x%x
               |""".stripMargin, seed, difficulty)
  }

  when (!enabled && RegNext(enabled)) {
    printf(s"[info] $name disabled\n")
  }
```

I found this a bit odd so started investigated. So far, I know chisel3 has a `printf` function, and the documentation says it "prints a message in simulation." Does this apply to verilog simulations, scalaland simulations, or both? If I use chisel3's `printf` does this result in `$display` statements in the verilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (very exciting) answer to this is yes. While not `$display` statements, the generated verilog includes `$fwrite`.

Scastie example of `$fwrite` here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Hajn4b1sTDmcxk5sBHw7pQ

[at some point I'll learn the new firrtl annotation to disable rand]